# Delphi RAD Studio 10.2 Error reading Form1.FormFactor.Width Property FormFactor.Width does not exist

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have one problem with RAD Studio 10.2 for old version XE5 it worked ok.
It gives an exception error:

> "Error reading Form1.FormFactor.Width Property FormFactor.Width does not exist"

when I try to open my main form.

```
unit FormEmail;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Edit, IdMessage, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase,
  IdSMTP, System.StrUtils,IdSSLOpenSSL, FMX.Controls.Presentation, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;
```

Comment: You are mixing firemonkey FMX units with VCL units. You can't use both.

Comment: @LURD I think that this is a trap a few newbies might fall into. I think it is worth putting your comment up as an answer.

Comment: @DSM, ok, done.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing firemonkey `FMX` units with `VCL` units. They can't coexist.

Remove the VCL units from your uses in the `FormEmail` unit, and your code will compile.

Comment: The question states that _for old version XE5 it worked ok_. Is that possible? If so, it might be worth mentioning that previous versions behaved differently.

Comment: @Nil, there has never been a `FormFactor` property in the VCL. I doubt that this code did compile in XE5.